# Effect size for meta-analysis from ANOVA with significant interaction term

Tags: anova, interaction, meta-analysis, effect-size

For a meta-analysis, I found a study in which the main effect of A on my dependant variable was not significant but the interaction of A and B and the interaction of A, B and C were. 
I also have only the data from an F-Test and the mean values of the variables.

Since I am only interested in the effect of A on my dependant variable, all the meta-analysis literature I read suggests to calculate the effect size based on this (main) effect.

But many source on the internet emphasize that one cannot easily interpret the main effect of an ANOVA in which the interaction term is significant. Thus, it feels incorrect to ignore this matter and just calculate the effect size based on the main effect.

Can anybody tell me how to proceed in this situation?

Comment: If you know that the interaction between A & B & others involving C are statistically significant how can you ignore the individual effects of B & C.

Comment: The meta-analysis adresses only the effect of A on the DV. Also, all other studies except this one did not measure B or C. So I really want to know about the individual effect of A on the DV.

Comment: I heard you stay that but why don't you think the meta-analysis is valid when you are including this study?

Comment: I want to include this study, i'm just wondering how to calculate the effect size for the effect of A on my DV.

Comment: Are A B and C continuous variables or categorical ones?

Comment: they are all categorical

Comment: I just encountered https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34150/whats-the-appropriate-way-to-calculate-an-effect-size-when-there-is-an-interact?rq=1, where you answer the same question for a regression case Mr. Flom. 

Is there any other practical option for my study with the interaction effect except excluding it for the MA?

Comment: To respond to someone who is not the author of the post, you need to type @ before their name (like @Swarley, though this is not necessary here because you're the author).

Comment: I had forgotten about that answer. But it doesn't say you have to exclude it, it says that when there is an interaction you can only examine the main effect at one level of the IV at a time. Since your IVs here are categorical, you may be able to look at every level (you will have to adjust N).